Get access to ComponentActivity inside Flutter Plugin
I need to get access to ComponentActivity to open ShopifyCheckoutSheetKit (Android) inside a Flutter Plugin.
checkout-sheet-kit-android
I am able to get access to Context and Activity via ActivityAware interface:
class ShopifyCheckoutSheetKitPlugin : FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware {
    private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel

    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var activity: Activity

    override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "shopify_checkout_sheet_kit_plugin_android")
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
        context = flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext
    }

    override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
        when (call.method) {
            "showCheckoutSheet" -> showCheckoutSheet()
            else -> result.notImplemented()
        }
    }

    private fun showCheckoutSheet() {
        ShopifyCheckoutSheetKit.present(checkoutUrl, componentActivity, processor)
    }
}

However I need to cast it to ComponentActivity or somehowe get ComponentActivity in ShopifyCheckoutSheetKitPlugin.
The question is how can I get ComponentActivity inside ShopifyCheckoutSheetKitPlugin class.
